# what does the sine function tell you about an input

Tags: trigonometry, intuition, signal-processing

Intuitively, I'm trying to understand the significance of the input in a sine function. I'm currently, trying to develop intuition behind sinusoids and what the input tells you about the output and vice versa. What is the significance of the fundamental frequency being in terms of radians/sec ?

Comment: Complex sinusioids ($e^{j \omega t}$) are eigenfunctions of linear time invariant systems - that is, they come out with the same frequency but possibly different phase and amplitude. You can also use Fourier transforms to represent inputs to the system in terms of complex sinusoids and decompose the outputs in the same manner.

Comment: This is a very unclear question, to me. Can you give an example of another function where you have such intuition?

Comment: Perhaps [this image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unfasor.gif) will help you picture things.

Comment: I think your question would be clearer if you wrote some examples containing _specific equations_ that you needed help to understand.